# Oracle table partition

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, partitioning

Can any one help me referring a book for Oracle table partitioning. Oracle 10g complete reference contains the basics but i need elaborate with example.

Thank you

Comment: The online is fairly complete.  It would be helpful if you could expand your question to include what additional you need and/or what concepts need further elucidation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle has documentation available online with examples [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/partconc.htm).

Answer (score 2):

I think the discussion in Tom Kyte's book "Effective Oracle by Design" (ch. 3 - Architectural Decisions) does a good job of outlining the concepts as well as the pros and cons of partitioning.

Answer (score 1):

I have ["Oracle Database 10g Performance Tuning *Tips & Techniques*"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0072263059) by Richard Niemiec on my desk. It's a great reference for many Oracle performance issues and has quite a bit of material on partitioning.

Answer (score 0):

please refer this documents...link http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/partconc.htm